# ProGuard removing method call creating useless code

Tags: java, methods, proguard

So I have small interface

```
public interface IPlayersStorage
{
    // other methods...
    public boolean addException(final String nick);
    // other methods...
}
```

and class "PlayersStorage" that implements it: (only used part)

```
public class PlayersStorage implements IPlayersStorage
{
    private static final PlayersStorage               inst          = new PlayersStorage();
    private final        Set<String>                  exceptions    = new HashSet<>(50);

    @Override
    public boolean addException(final String nick)
    {
        return ! this.exceptions.add(nick);
    }

    public static PlayersStorage getStorage()
    {
        return inst;
    }
}
```

And in some place I use that method using that code:

```
for (final String player : this.cfg.getStringList("Exceptions"))
{
    PlayersStorage.getStorage().addException(player);
}
```

And ProGuard change it to:

```
for (Iterator localIterator1 = this.cfg.getStringList("Exceptions").iterator(); localIterator1.hasNext();)
{
  localIterator1.next();

  PlayersStorage.getStorage();  // it's get object, but don't do anything with it...
}
```

The only possible fix that I found, is add static method to `PlayersStorage`

```
public static boolean staticAddException(final String nick)
{
    return inst.addException(nick);
}
```

And then use it (instead of old code)

```
for (final String player : this.cfg.getStringList("Exceptions"))
{
    PlayersStorage.staticAddException(player);
}
```

Then works... (ProGuard keep method call) but adding static methods for every method from interface isn't good idea.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard only removes method invocations if they don't have any effect (doesn't seem to be the case here), or if you have specified `-assumenosideffects` for the methods. You should check your configuration and remove any such option.

Alternatively, your decompiler may be having problems decompiling the code. You should then check the actual bytecode with `javap -c`.